# Limiting traffic in network

Tags: limits

Can I limit bandwidth for every client or vlan in my network ?
The purpose is to prevent downloading managers from taking all the bandwidth and cause other computers to have a very slow Internet speed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is "YES", you can do it! Refer to this: [Traffic shaping - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping)

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I understand that, but question is very broad and so is the answer. it really is impossible to provide more precise answer w/out knowing OS and whatever else is relevant.

Comment: -1 - this is a poor answer. If there aren't enough details in the question for you to provide a good answer, then ask for clarification in a comment.